# Table does not exist on testing a read-only table (Django)

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-migrations

I have a `Django` project. There are 2 databases in this project and I've written a `Router` to make one of them `readonly`. I've written some unit tests that use this `readonly` database, but when I run `python manage.py test` it says

> ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_arzesh-db.company' doesn't
>   exist")

Here is the settings of databases:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'broker-website',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'OPTIONS': {
            "init_command": "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;",
        },
    },
    'arzesh-db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'arzesh-db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'TEST_DATABASE': 'default',
    },
    'TEST': {
        'CHARSET': 'utf8',
        'COALATION': 'utf8-unicode-ci',
    }
}
```

And here is the code of my router:

```
class Router(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'arzesh':
            return 'arzesh-db'
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'arzesh':
            return 'arzesh-db'
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
        """
        return True

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth_db'
        database.
        """
        if app_label == 'arzesh':
            return False
        return True
```

Here is the model that is in the readonly database:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tick

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tick = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=32)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'company'
```

and here is the line that gets error in unittest:

```
company.objects.create(id=1, tick='a', name='a')
```

Comment: @e4c5 I edited the post and added the information. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it's inaccurate to say,

> I've written some unit tests that use this readonly database

That is because

> Tests that require a database (namely, model tests) will not use your
>   “real” (production) database. Separate, blank databases are created
>   for the tests.
>   ...
>   The default test database names are created by prepending test_ to the
>   value of each NAME in DATABASES

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

This is confirmed by the fact that the error is

> ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table '**test_arzesh**-db.company' doesn't exist")

Right, so how does the test database get created? Based on the contents of your migrations. But you have

```
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'company'
```

The `managed = False` here means that no migration will be created, so the table will not exist in your test database. Hence the error.

**Solution.**
Manually add a migration with RunSQL that creates this table. Use the SQL from `SHOW CREATE TABLE company` for that. To do that first do

```
./manage.py makemigrations myapp --empty
```

And the edit the newly created migrations file to add the RunPython or [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) code into it. The SQL that you pass into RunSQL is the SQL you generated by `SHOW CREATE TBABLE company` in your mysql console. Please refer [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) docs for additional information and samples.

Comment: I don't understand the solution, what should I do exactly? Should I create the tables manually?